# Управление устройствами из powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-7

Как включить и выключить сетевой адаптер с помощью powershell в windows 7?

Comment: Какая версия Windwos?

Comment: @becouse windows 7

Answer (score 0):

Для Windows 10

1. Список адаптеров

   Get-NetAdapter | format-table
2. Изменяем состояние адаптера (отключаем)

   Disable-NetAdapter -Name "ADAPTER-NAME" -Confirm:$false
3. Изменяем состояние адаптера (включаем)

   Enable-NetAdapter -Name "ADAPTER-NAME" -Confirm:$false

Comment: В windows 7, psversion 2.0 не работает.

Comment: 2 и 3 пункт одинаковые, так должно быть? :)